# New Ticket Alert not working for Organization Account Manager

Tags: osticket

When a new ticket is created then it sends a alert message to Admin Email, Department Manager and Department Members.

Enabling New Ticket Alert does not work for Organization Account Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. go to Admin panel -> Settings -> Alerts & Notices -> New Ticket Alert and check
2. go to Admin panel -> Staff -> Department -> YOUR DEPARTMENT and check 
   "New Ticket"
3. go to Admin panel -> Emails -> Template -> New Ticket Alert and check

Restart server. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found that "New ticket alerts" do not get sent out (except to admin email) if you are using Ticket Filters to auto-assign agents or teams.

We use the ticket filters, so we create an email group for example notifications@example.com, and apply that to the admin email.